# How to access properties on Apollo GraphQL data response in TypeScript React application

Tags: apollo-client, react-typescript

I'm converting a non TypeScript React application to a TypeScript one and not sure how to best handle the data repsonse that Apollos useQuery provides.

Take the following graphql query:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const FETCH_COMMENTS = gql(`
  query GetComments($entityId: ID!, $context: String!) {
     commentsByEntityIdAndContext(entityId: $entityId, context: $context) {
       totalCount
       items {
         id
         createdByName
         createdDate
         value
       }
    }
  }
`);
```

I am using the gql function from the graphql-tag library to expose queries as a DocumentNode, otherwise the compiler complains.

These generated files also then provides the type for the query response CommentsByEntityIdAndContextCollectionSegment which im importing into my component and using as below:

```
interface CommentsQueryResponse {
    commentsByEntityIdAndContext?: CommentsByEntityIdAndContextCollectionSegment
}

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery<CommentsQueryResponse>(FETCH_COMMENTS, {
    variables: { entityId: entityId, context: context },
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
    nextFetchPolicy: "cache-first"
});
```

I can then access the items on the respsonse by:

```
data?.commentsByEntityIdAndContext?.items
```

So it works, but given this is just one query in many that I need to work with and convert to TS, I'm not happy with having to specify the CommentsQueryResponse interface for every query. Is there an easier way or better practice to how you should access props on a data response from Apollo?

EDIT

To provide further context I did initially generate Type definitions as directed by Apollo and used the gql function '../src/**generated**/gql', but this led to compiler errors:

```
Argument of [object Object] passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode. You may need to use 'graphql-tag' or another method to convert your operation into a document
```

My generated gql file is as follows

````
 /* eslint-disable */
    import * as types from './graphql';
    import { TypedDocumentNode as DocumentNode } from '@graphql-typed-document-node/core';

const documents = [];
/**
 * The gql function is used to parse GraphQL queries into a document that can be used by GraphQL clients.
 *
 *
 * @example
 * ```ts
 * const query = gql(`query GetUser($id: ID!) { user(id: $id) { name } }`);
 * ```
 *
 * The query argument is unknown!
 * Please regenerate the types.
 */
export function gql(source: string): unknown;

export function gql(source: string) {
  return (documents as any)[source] ?? {};
}

export type DocumentType<TDocumentNode extends DocumentNode<any, any>> = TDocumentNode extends DocumentNode<  infer TType,  any>  ? TType  : never;
````

Comment: Usually you would set up the codegen and never type a single TypeScript type by hand. See the documentation: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/

Comment: @phry I did follow that, but the compiler complained that:

Argument of [object Object] passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode. You may need to use 'graphql-tag' or another method to convert your operation into a document         

I had to use graphql-tag library instead to get round this. Is there a way round this?

Comment: So you did `import { gql } from '../src/__generated__/gql';`? I mean, you can look at that generated file and see what it generated. Sharing that might help.

Comment: @phry Updated Question to provide

Comment: That file is missing your query. Probably the codegen didn't pick it up. Check the file pattern in the codegen config, maybe it doesn't match your file paths?

Comment: @phry Spot on. My queries were still in a .js file and so weren't picked up. Rerun and now behaving exactly as I expected it to. Thankyou

Comment: @phry Feel free to add an official Answer and Ill mark it as accepted